# trigger Android application from Web Application

Tags: android, asp.net

Hello all my problem is :
We have to create a system in which we need to create both web(ASP.NET C#) and android application and we have to synchronize data on both interface.
So **is there any method/Way to trigger Android application from Web Application(ASP.NET C#).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where you want to trigger?

For synchronization of data, you need to create a WebService interface through which you can send/receive data whenever you want from/to mobile.

Comment: I want to receive data on Android app without sending request to web service

Comment: Then you can implement "Push Notification" kind of functionality.

Comment: Thanks PM for finding solution. We can synchronize using C2DM for more information see http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html